# ¿Cómo obtener el STATUS de todos los repositorios GIT de un directorio?

Tags: linux, git, bash, debian

Quiero hacer un ejecutable para shell o bash que escanee el directorio completo buscando repositorios git

```
find . ! -readable -prune -o -name ".git" -type d -prune -print
```

Luego ejecute (cambiando el directorio de `--git-dir`)

```
git --git-dir="/var/www/miRepo/.git" fetch --all -q
```

Luego algo como esto

```
git --git-dir="/var/www/miRepo/.git" diff --stat | tail -n1
```

Me gustaría poder tener estadísticas sobre el estado del repo algo como

```
Ramas Remotas | Ramas Locales | Cambios (new-mod-del)            | código
master          master          M 123 - A 1 - D 1 - R 12 - C 12   (+)1223 (-)122
production    | no seguimiento
```

Que se resuman los cambios según los estados de `git status` en la [documentacion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_output). Me gustaría tener un archivo del tipo sh que reciba el directorio como parametro. Pero no excluyo otras soluciones en otros lenguajes, ya que me sirven de base para hacer lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes buena parte de los comandos, así que solamente hace falta que lo unas y des vueltas sobre los resultados.

Esto se puede hacer usando [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854) para alimentar el bucle con la salida de `find`:

```
while IFS= read -r repo; do ... done < <(find...)
```

En este caso puedes pasar el directorio al script como parámetro:

```
dir=$1
while IFS= read -r repo
do
    git --git-dir="$repo" fetch --all -q
    data=$(git --git-dir="$repo" diff --stat | tail -n1)
    printf "%s --- %s\n" "$repo" "$data"
done < <(find "$dir" ! -readable -prune -o -name ".git" -type d -prune -print)
```

Ve una muestra de ejecución:

```
$ bash status_repo.sh "/home/yo/repos"
/home/yo/repos/proy1/.git ---  69 files changed, 19862 deletions(-)
/home/yo/repos/proy2/.git ---  24 files changed, 2368 deletions(-)
/home/yo/repos/proy3/.git ---  9 files changed, 56 deletions(-)
/home/yo/repos/proy4/.git ---  30 files changed, 1144 deletions(-)
```

Ya dejo como ejercicio diseccionar la salida de los datos para que se ajuste al formato que querrías tener.

Comment: hola. No funciona en windows? 
`usuario@usuario-pc MINGW64 /d
$ sh asd.sh "/d"
asd.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token \`<'
asd.sh: line 7: \`done < <(find "$dir" ! -readable -prune -o -name ".git" -type d -prune -print)'`

Comment: @ArieCwHat no me das suficientes detalles para saber qué puede estar fallando. Edita tu pregunta con estos datos, así como versiones que estás utilizando.

Comment: Estaba intentando hacer correr el archivo .sh con la consola de git-bash en windows usando el comando `sh status_repo.sh "/home/yo/repos"` pero me dió ese error del comentario anterior. Ahora lo he probado en Debian de la misma forma: y me da este error `scan.sh: 7: scan.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`. Me he dado cuenta que en Debian he usado `sh scan.sh "."` en vez de `bash scan.sh "."`. Con sh no funciona, pero con bash si. (aun soy principiante xd). Pero si me funcionó, ahora voy a intentar formatear las salidas :)

Comment: Pensaba que shell y bash eran intercambiables, pero acabo de leer [Differences between sh & bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) y no :P. bash ha mutado con el tiempo y algunos scripts no son compatibles